# How to get list of beans defined in a java config class?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, spring-ioc

A spring java configuration class can have more than one bean defined in it. I am aware on how to obtain a single bean which is defined in a java spring configuration class.  Some thing like -

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new  AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(BeanConfigurer.class);
ClassA a = ctx.getBean(ClassA.class);
```

But I want to know if using a single method call is there a way to obtain every bean defined in the configuration class.
The bean configurer class is something like below. All classes - ClassA, ClassB, ClassC extend a common parent ClassAlphabet.

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public ClassA classA()
    {
        return new ClassA () ;
    }


    @Bean
    public ClassB classB()
    {
        return new ClassB () ;
    }


    @Bean
    public ClassC classC()
    {
        return new ClassC () ;
    }

}
```

And I am interested in doing a single method call and get all the beans in to a list. something like below:

```
 List<ClassAlphabet> listOfClasses = ctx.getBeans(ClassAlphabets.class);
```

or simply

```
List<ClassAlphabet> listOfClasses = ctx.getBeans();
```

Is it possible??

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ctx.getBeansOfType(ClassAlphabets.class)`.

```
<T> Map<String, T> getBeansOfType(Class<T> type) throws BeansException;
```

More details [in the Javadocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html#getBeansOfType-java.lang.Class-).

This does not necessarily do this: "get list of beans defined in a java config class" but it **does** meet the requirement implied by this quasi code from the OP:

```
List<ClassAlphabet> listOfClasses = ctx.getBeans(ClassAlphabets.class); 
List<ClassAlphabet> listOfClasses = ctx.getBeans();
```